# extract column names from table DDL

Tags: text-processing

I have a text file with list of tables. I need to extract the columns for each table and need to write it to another csv file along with table name.

Example

```
describe test_table
+-----------+------------+
| col_name  | data_type  |
+-----------+------------+
| Name      | string     |
| Age       | string     |
+-----------+------------+
```

I need to create csv file with below details

```
test_table,Name,Age
```

Could you please suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
$1 == "describe" {
    out = $2
    next
}
/^[+]/ {
    mod = (++cnt % 3)
    if ( mod == 0 ) {
        print out
    }
    next
}
mod == 2 {
    out = out "," $2
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
test_table,Name,Age
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works .

Comment: Hi Is there any way to add data type too along with table name ?

Comment: You're welcome. Sure, anythings possible but accept an answer to the question you asked (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and then ask a new question about your updated requirements as [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are strongly discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of one way to do this in perl:

```perl
$ cat extract-column-names.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl -l

while(<>) {
  # Is the current line a "describe" line or are we at the End Of File?
  if (m/describe\s+(.*)/i || eof) {
    # Do we already a table name and column names?
    if ($table && @columns) {
      print join(",", $table, @columns);
      # clear current @columns array
      @columns=();
    };
    # extract table name
    $table = $1;
    next;
  };

  # skip header lines, ruler lines, and empty lines
  next if (m/col_name|-\+-|^\s*$/);

  # extract column name with regex capture group
  if (m/^\|\s+(\S+)\s+\|/) { push @columns, $1 };
}
```

Sample input, with more than one table description:

```
$ cat table.txt
describe test_table
+-----------+------------+
| col_name  | data_type  |
+-----------+------------+
| Name      | string     |
| Age       | string     |
+-----------+------------+

describe test_table2
+------------+------------+
| col_name   | data_type  |
+------------+------------+
| FirstName  | string     |
| MiddleName | string     |
| LastName   | string     |
+------------+------------+
```

Sample run:

```
$ ./extract-column-names.pl table.txt
test_table,Name,Age
test_table2,FirstName,MiddleName,LastName
```

BTW, this script can also handle stdin (e.g. `cat table.txt | ./extract-column-names.pl`) and multiple filename arguments (e.g. `./extract-column-names.pl table1.txt table2.txt ... tableN.txt`).

Also, it would not be difficult to add the ability to extract the `data_type` for each column too.  This could be stored in a separate array (e.g. `@types`) or you could change the script to use a hash (using `col_name` as the key, and `data_type` as the value).  If using a hash, however, it's important to remember that they're inherently un-ordered so you would still need the `@columns` array to remember the order that the columns were seen.

---

One-liner version:

```
$ perl -lne 'if (m/describe\s+(.*)/i || eof) {if ($table && @columns) {print join(",", $table, @columns);@columns=()}$table = $1;next};next if (m/col_name|-\+-|^\s*$/);if (m/^\|\s+(\S+)\s+\|/) {push @columns, $1};' table.txt 
test_table,Name,Age
test_table2,FirstName,MiddleName,LastName
```

Answer (score 0):

Prepare the testing environnement :

```
# Get all the table
mysql -S /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock -D mysql -e 'SHOW TABLES;' > all_tables

# Get all the column for each tables
xargs -a all_tables -i -- /bin/sh -c '
    printf "describe %s\\n" "$1"
    mysql -S /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock -D mysql -te "DESC $1"
' _Z_ {} >> tables
```

This is en extract and the files looks like your sample data :

```
describe column_stats
+---------------+-----------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type                                    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+-----------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| db_name       | varchar(64)                             | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| table_name    | varchar(64)                             | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| column_name   | varchar(64)                             | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| min_value     | varbinary(255)                          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| max_value     | varbinary(255)                          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| nulls_ratio   | decimal(12,4)                           | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| avg_length    | decimal(12,4)                           | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| avg_frequency | decimal(12,4)                           | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| hist_size     | tinyint(3) unsigned                     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| hist_type     | enum('SINGLE_PREC_HB','DOUBLE_PREC_HB') | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| histogram     | varbinary(255)                          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------+-----------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
describe columns_priv
+-------------+----------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------------------------------+
| Field       | Type                                         | Null | Key | Default             | Extra                         |
+-------------+----------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------------------------------+
| Host        | char(60)                                     | NO   | PRI |                     |                               |
| Db          | char(64)                                     | NO   | PRI |                     |                               |
| User        | char(80)                                     | NO   | PRI |                     |                               |
| Table_name  | char(64)                                     | NO   | PRI |                     |                               |
| Column_name | char(64)                                     | NO   | PRI |                     |                               |
| Timestamp   | timestamp                                    | NO   |     | current_timestamp() | on update current_timestamp() |
| Column_priv | set('Select','Insert','Update','References') | NO   |     |                     |                               |
+-------------+----------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------------------------------+
```

Parsing that using `awk` :

```
awk -F'|' -v OFS=, '
    match($0, /^describe /) {
        tbl = substr($0, RSTART+RLENGTH)
        c = 3
        next
    } 

    /^[+]/ && c < 0 {print tbl}

    c-- <= 0 {
        gsub(/ */, "", $2)
        tbl = tbl OFS $2
    } 
' tables
```

Comment: Yeah , I need to get the table and column name details for all the tables present in the schema . Thanks for detailed solution

Comment: Is there any way to add data type also along with column name ?

Comment: @user514629 yes, but you should ask it in  another question. See Ed Morton comment.