# Extract Metadata from DDL

Tags: text-processing, text-formatting

I have a created a file with list of tables present in a particular schema. I need to extract the column details for each table and need to write it to another file

```
describe test_table
+-----------+------------+------------+
| col_name  | data_type  |Comment     |
+-----------+------------+------------+
| Name      | string     |My Name     |
| Age       | string     |My Age      |
+-----------+------------+------------+
```

Output file should have below details.

```
test_table,Name,String,My Name
test_table,Age,string,My Age
```

Comment: You say `I have a created a file with list of tables` but your sample input appears to only contain 1 table. If you need help parsing a file that contains multiple tables then you should [edit] your question to provide sample input/output that contains more than 1 table. 2 should be enough.

Comment: Please [accept an answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) to [your previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/690840/extract-column-names-from-table-ddl) and then try to adapt that answer to your new problem before posting a new question related to it and add your current code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

```perl
$ cat extract-columns.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl -l

while(<>) {
  # Is the current line a "describe" line?
  if (m/describe\s+(.*)/i || eof) {
    $table = $1;
    next;
  };

  # skip header lines, ruler lines, and empty lines
  next if (m/col_name|-\+-|^\s*$/);

  # remove pipes and spaces at beginning and end of line
  s/^\|\s*|\s*\|\s*$//g;

  # remove spaces surrounding pipe characters
  s/\s*\|\s*/|/g;

  # extract field name by splitting input line on pipe chars
  my ($name, $type, $comment) = split /\|/;
  print join(",", $table, $name, $type, $comment);
}
```

Sample output:

```
$ ./extract-columns.pl table2.txt 
test_table,Name,string,My Name
test_table,Age,string,My Age
```

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`:

```
awk -v OFS="," 'NR==1{ tblName=$2; FS="|"; next }
NF>1 && NR>4{ $1=tblName; gsub(/ *, */, ","); sub(/,$/, ""); print }' infile
```

Output:

```
test_table,Name,string,My Name
test_table,Age,string,My Age
```

with `gsub()` we are removing the leading and trailing spaces from each fields;
with `sub()` we are removing the trailing comma.